# iText 7 - How do I ignore page rotation when adding content or signature

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, itext7

**Can I ignore the page rotation for content in iText 7 (I have tried SetIgnorePageRotationForContent(true) method.)**

When I try to add any content to the rotated pdf page, the point (0,0) of the content I want to add also rotates / changes.

**Not Rotated Scanned Document Result (Correct Case)**

[image: Correct Case Image]

I want to positing this content top left corner of document.

**180 Degrees Rotated Scanned Document Result (Unwanted and Incorrect Case)**

[image: Incorrect Case Image]

While trying to position it in the top-left corner of the document, the same code adds the content to the bottom-right of the document.

My Code is:

```
//ADD VERIFICATION
var ms = new MemoryStream(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filePath));
PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(ms).SetUnethicalReading(true), new PdfWriter(fileTempPath), new StampingProperties().UseAppendMode());

ms.Close();
ms.Dispose();
var page = document.GetPage(1);
           
var callbackUrl = Url.Action("DocumentVerification", "Home", new { documentId = item.Id }, protocol: Request.Scheme);
BarcodeQRCode qr = new BarcodeQRCode(callbackUrl);
PdfCanvas canvas = new PdfCanvas(page.SetIgnorePageRotationForContent(true).NewContentStreamAfter(), page.GetResources(), document);

Table table = new Table(4).UseAllAvailableWidth();
Image qrimage = new Image(qr.CreateFormXObject(document)).SetAutoScale(true);
Text text = new Text("TEXT Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet\nLorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet\n");

PdfFont font = PdfFontFactory.CreateFont(tfffile, PdfEncodings.IDENTITY_H, true);
text.SetFontSize(7).SetFont(font);
Paragraph p = new Paragraph(text);
iText.Layout.Element.Cell cell2 = new iText.Layout.Element.Cell(1, 3).Add(p);
cell2.SetHeight(40).SetHorizontalAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.LEFT).SetBorder(Border.NO_BORDER);
iText.Layout.Element.Cell cell = new iText.Layout.Element.Cell(1, 1).Add(qrimage);
cell.SetHeight(40).SetHorizontalAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.LEFT).SetBorder(Border.NO_BORDER);
table.AddCell(cell);
table.AddCell(cell2);

var rect = new Rectangle(3f, 802f, 225f, 40f);
Canvas qrcanvas = new Canvas(canvas, rect).SetFixedPosition(3f, 802f, 225f);
qrcanvas.SetBorder(Border.NO_BORDER).Add(table);
document.Close();
PdfDocument documentNew = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(fileTempPath).SetUnethicalReading(true), new PdfWriter(filePath), new StampingProperties().UseAppendMode());
documentNew.Close();
System.IO.File.Delete(fileTempPath);
//ADD VERIFICATION END
```

This code block contains `.SetFixedPosition(3f, 802f, 225f);` and `.SetIgnorePageRotationForContent(true)` tryings. These are not working for this case.

Comment: Actually your *Unwanted and Incorrect Case* looks like there is a 180° page rotation **which iText does ignore** but not your viewer. Thus, your addition ends up in the upper left corner of the unrotated page and, therefore, in the viewer upside down in the bottom right corner. You call that "unwanted", so apparently you actually don't want iText to ignore the page rotation.

Comment: Or do you want all PDF processors (not only iText but also your viewer) to ignore rotation?

Comment: Actually i dont want to rotate qr code and text.
As in the second image, the main pdf content should remain as rotated and my qr code and text should not be rotated according to the rotation angle of the page.

Comment: Is there any automatic way to doing this like as i understand .SetIgnorePageRotationForContent(true)?

Comment: I'm still not completely sure which result you really want. Have you tried simply calling `page.SetRotation(0)` after retrieving it (`var page = document.GetPage(1)`), does this do what you want?

Comment: I want something very simple.
I want to add qr code and text into a rotated pdf file. Just that qr code and text 
 behaves that the page has not been rotated. So I don't want have to manually specify a new location.

I guess there's no choice but to manually calculate position, based on the angle of rotation.

Answer (score 1):

I just struggled with the same issue.
No matter what I tried, the rotation would keep applying for my text content that I added even with the parameters `.SetIgnorePageRotationForContent(true)` or `.SetFixedPosition(...)`

The issue was solved by changing the initialization of the PdfCanvas :

Add the line `page.SetIgnorePageRotationForContent(true);` after `var page = document.GetPage(1);`

And change the line

`PdfCanvas canvas = new PdfCanvas(page.SetIgnorePageRotationForContent(true).NewContentStreamAfter(), page.GetResources(), document);`

by

`PdfCanvas canvas = new PdfCanvas(page);`