# iText7 - How to ignore page rotation when writing UNDER the original content

Tags: itext7

This page [iText 7 - How do I ignore page rotation when adding content or signature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63916641/itext-7-how-do-i-ignore-page-rotation-when-adding-content-or-signature) explains how to ignore page rotation when writing OVER the original content, and it works great:

```cs
PdfPage page = pdfDoc.GetPage(1);
page.SetIgnorePageRotationForContent(true);
var pdfCanvas = new PdfCanvas(page, true);
//write something to pdfCanvas
pdfCanvas.Release();
```

But how to do the same when writing UNDER the original content? By reverse-engineering the `public PdfCanvas(PdfPage page, bool wrapOldContent)` constructor source code, I managed to make it work as follows:

```cs
PdfPage page = pdfDoc.GetPage(1);
var pdfCanvas = new PdfCanvas(page.NewContentStreamBefore(), page.GetResources(), pdfDoc);
PdfOutputStream pdfCanvasOutputStream = pdfCanvas.GetContentStream().GetOutputStream();
pdfCanvasOutputStream.WriteBytes(ByteUtils.GetIsoBytes("q\n"));
Rectangle pageSizeWithRotation = page.GetPageSizeWithRotation();

switch (page.GetRotation())
{
    case 90:
        pdfCanvas.ConcatMatrix(0, 1, -1, 0, pageSizeWithRotation.GetTop(), 0);
        break;
    case 180:
        pdfCanvas.ConcatMatrix(-1, 0, 0, -1, pageSizeWithRotation.GetRight(), pageSizeWithRotation.GetTop());
        break;
    case 270:
        pdfCanvas.ConcatMatrix(0, -1, 1, 0, 0, pageSizeWithRotation.GetRight());
        break;
}

//write something to pdfCanvas

pdfCanvasOutputStream.WriteBytes(ByteUtils.GetIsoBytes("Q\n"));
pdfCanvas.Release();
```

But is there a better way?

Comment: AFAICS there indeed is no existing convenience method for drawing under the existing content ignoring page rotation. If the `PdfCanvas.ApplyRotation` method was public, one could have used that; unfortunately it isn't. Thus, I don't see a really better way either.

Comment: @mkl Thank you so much, you're very helpful as always! I'm currently moving some code from iText v5 to v7, and one question I have not been able to solve (though it's not blocking me right now) is how to predictably write a 1-line `Paragraph` at a given `y` position. Paragraph text's baseline always appears above the `y` passed to `Paragraph.SetFixedPosition(x, y, width)`, but I cannot figure out how to calculate this gap between `y` and the text's baseline?

Comment: *"Paragraph text's baseline always appears above the `y` passed to ..."* - if I remember correctly, iText 7 positions paragraphs not by baseline but by bounding box corner.

Comment: *iText 7 positions paragraphs bounding box corner* - yes that seems to be the case, but how to get the delta between the bbox `y` and the text's baseline? With `PdfCanvas` I can use `pdfCanvas.BeginText().MoveText(x, y).ShowText("abc").EndText()` to position the text's baseline at the passed `y`. Can't find a way to do the same with `Canvas` though? Seems the only way to write text to `Canvas` is to use a `Paragraph`? I use `Canvas` to write to `PdfFormXObject` and then position `PdfFormXObject` in `PdfCanvas` via `pdfCanvas.AddXObjectWithTransformationMatrix()`.

Comment: Can't you add the text directly to a `PdfCavas` of the `PdfFormXObject`?

Comment: That worked, thanks! I did not realise I could write to `PdfFormXObject` using `PdfCavas`. I followed the example from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63055889/what-is-an-alternate-way-to-implement-pdfcontentbyte-and-pdftemplate-in-itext-7, which uses `Canvas`.